# Making a Choropleth in R without using a gradient

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm pretty new to R and I am trying to map the distribution of an ant species in Argentina using the adm1 (or state) divisions.

I have downloaded data from the GADM website and I have a csv file that I've created that contains info saying whether the species is present or absent in each adm1.
Even though I don't have a gradient can I still make a choropleth? If not, what other types of maps could I use?

I've looked at several sites including [Infomaps using R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/infomaps-using-r-visualizing-german-unemployment-rates-by-district-on-a-map/), [How to make choropleths in R](http://prabhasp.com/wp/how-to-make-choropleths-in-r/), and the Choropleth Map Challenge, which have been really helpful but they all have numeric data and I'm using a present(1) or absent(0) column. The different packages I've tried are `sp`(with `RColorBrewer`), `ggplot2`, `rgeos`, and `maptools`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
library(sp)
library(RColorBrewer)
write.csv(atr, "atr_data.csv")
atr_data<-read.csv("atr_data.csv", header=TRUE)
  spcode country_code adm1_code newcol
1    atr          VEN     VE.AR      0
2    atr          PRY     PY.CE      0
3    atr          PAN     PA.CL      0
4    atr          PAN     PA.CL      0
5    atr          PAN     PA.PN      0
6    atr          PAN     PA.PN      0
```

I'm in the process of making a column with the full adm1 names instead of the codes so that it will match up with the GADM file (so I haven't written the code to merge the data yet).

```
#to retrieve map for Argentina ARG
con <- url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/ARG_adm1.RData")
print(load(con))
close(con)
#to generate random colors on map
col = rainbow(length(levels(gadm$NAME_1)))
spplot(gadm, "NAME_1", col.regions=col, main="ARG Regions", colorkey = FALSE, lwd=.4,col="white")  
#this piece of code is a mess  
col_no <- as.factor(as.numeric(atr_data$newcol[order],
                c(0,1)))
levels(col_no)<- c("0", "1")
gadm$col_no <- col_no
myPalette<-brewer.pal(3, "Purples")
spplot(gadm, "col_no", col=grey(.9), 
col.regions=myPalette,
main="Distribution of Atratus in Argentina")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of minor issues that come up in the example you've provided.

First, the data slot for spatial polygon dataframes can be accessed with `gadm@data$col_no` instead of `gadm$col_no`. Once you've finished filling out your presence/absence table, either by accessing the slot directly, or using `spCbind` in the `maptools` package allows you to add the presence/absence data to the spatial polygon data frame.

Second, if you have only 2 levels in your `col_no` factor, you will have to subset `MyPalette` to 2 colours since the Brewer palette will only work with a minimum of 3 levels.

```
library(sp)
library(RColorBrewer)
con <- url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/ARG_adm1.RData")
print(load(con))
close(con)

# Randomly assigning presence/absence data for display purposes only
gadm@data$col_no <- as.factor(rbinom(n = 24, size = 1, prob = 0.5))

myPalette <- brewer.pal(3, "Purples")

# col.regions is limited to 2 colors below with the middle color dropped.
spplot(gadm, zcol = "col_no", colorkey = TRUE, col.regions = myPalette[-2],
    main="Distribution of Atratus in Argentina")
```

[image]